# How to access UIButton (or any UIElement) inside UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm learning UITableView in Objective-C. Could you hint me how to access UIButton inside UITableviewHeaderFooterView subclass from my UIViewController class? Programatically, as I don't use IB.

Full code: https://gist.github.com/tomnaz/3d790b308d305af8b98c

```
[[??? btnEdit] addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(addNewItem:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in viewDidLoad, do it in viewForHeaderInSection: where you have a pointer to your header view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *headerReuseIdentifier = @"TableViewSectionHeaderViewIdentifier";

    ItemsHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:headerReuseIdentifier];
    [sectionHeaderView.btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initially create the buttons, you can store them in a property or array so you can easily find them later.

Alternatively, you could set a `tag` on the button, and then call `viewWithTag:` on your `UITableviewHeaderFooterView` subclass to find the button.

Comment: I have used the properties in the UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnEdit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnNew;`
, but I don't know how to access them inside the controller's viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Like this: `[self.btnEdit addTarget:<#…#> action:<#…#> forControlEvents:<#…#>];`

Comment: I mean how to access them inside the controller's viewDidLoad method. Using self won't work, right?